# BOOST TEST: Custom << operator for std::vector<float> type?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I've just started to learn Boost Test library (and C++ also).

I have this code inside a source file:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "../../MyLibrary/Matrices.h"

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<float>& result)
{
    os << result << std::endl;

    return os;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MatrixVectorProduct_1)
{
    std::vector<float> matrix = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
    std::vector<float> vector = { 1.0, 1.0 };
    std::vector<float> result = { 3.0, 7.0 };

    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(result, Matrices::MatrixVectorProduct(matrix, vector));
}
```

But, when I compile it I get this error:

```
MatricesTest.cpp
d:\vcpkg-master\installed\x86-windows\include\boost\test\tools\detail\print_helper.hpp(53): error C2338: Type has to implement operator<< to be printable
d:\vcpkg-master\installed\x86-windows\include\boost\test\tools\detail\print_helper.hpp(62): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::ostream &boost::test_tools::tt_detail::impl::boost_test_print_type<R>(std::ostream &,const T &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            R=std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>>,
            T=std::vector<float,std::allocator<float>>
        ]
```

There are a lot of more errors that I don't copy here for brevity.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I have used the code suggested by JohnFilleau's answer, but it still throws the same errors:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include "../../MyLibrary/Matrices.h"

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    os << '{';
    for (const auto& v : vec) {
        os << v << ' ';
    }
    os << '}';

    return os;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(MatrixVectorProduct_1)
{
    std::vector<float> matrix = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
    std::vector<float> vector = { 1.0, 1.0 };
    std::vector<float> result = { 3.0, 7.0 };

    BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL(result, Matrices::MatrixVectorProduct(matrix, vector));
}
```

Comment: `os << result` looks like the infinite recursion.

Comment: Here you go. Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999644/how-to-compare-vectors-with-boost-test

Comment: Have you tried with the comparison macro `BOOST_TEST` instead of `BOOST_REQUIRE_EQUAL` ? the link pointed by @JohnFilleau also mentions various ways of performing the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Boost Test seems not to be able to find the `operator<<` in the global namespace but only in the namespace of the second argument. So for `std::vector`, you must declare `operator<<` inside `namespace std`. This works for me, but it is likely [not a good idea](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std). This seems to be a general problem  of Boost Log, there is also a related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26155883/overload-operator-boost-log).

You are left with a few workarounds:

1. Write your test in a way that Boost Test does not want to print a `vector`, for example by using the methods mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999644/how-to-compare-vectors-with-boost-test).
2. Tell Boost Test not to print the type via `BOOST_TEST_DONT_PRINT_LOG_VALUE(std::vector<float>);`, [see the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/test_tools_support_for_logging/testing_tool_output_disable.html#ref_log_output_custom_avoid_printing).
3. Wrap your vector into a type you control and for which you can provide an overloaded `operator<<`, i.e.

```
struct WrapVec {
  std::vector<float> vec;
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & strm, WrapVec const & vec) {
  ...
  return strm;
}
```

The third option is particularly useful if you want to use `std::vector` as an argument to `BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE`, which raises the same compiler error for me.

Comment: *"This works for me..."* does not mean it is correct. It can still lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The safest option is to specialize `boost::test_tools::tt_detail::print_log_value` for the type you want to output:

```
template<>
struct boost::test_tools::tt_detail::print_log_value<std::vector<float>> {
    void operator()(std::ostream& os, std::vector<float> const& value) {
        os << '{';
        for (auto x : value)
            os << x << ' ';
        os << '}';
    }
};
```

This is still subject to the issue of "what if 2 people did this", but presumably you and your colleagues are the only people writing tests for your library, so you can coordinate to ensure that your log value printers don't conflict.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/5G6d3K15a).